# WPF ListView with GridViewColumns, won't scroll all the way to the right? Is there a horizontal scroll limit?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a ListView with with about 29 columns whose widths vary between 75 and 200. When viewing the data, if you scroll horizontally all the way to the right, you still can't get to the last 6 columns. You can resize the prior columns and see that the other columns are indeed there. It seems like there is some sort of scroll width limit or something? Does anyone have a clue about this? I never wanted this many columns but the person I'm creating it for wants them.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I can't comment yet but we would need a bit of code to see if you declared something the wrong way, need another control or whatever. XAML might suffice, maybe not, taking into account that ScrollViewer shouldn't inherit properties by default.

However, you should have a look at the ScrollabeWidth property of your ScrollViewer which contains the maximum amount of scrollable width through the content, althought it has no default value and should accomodate itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you tested a way like the following codes (ref: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330996/why-does-my-scrollviewer-destroy-my-grid-layout-wpf#7346503))? :

```
<Window x:Class="alternatingGridRow.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="Auto">

<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ShowGridLines="True" MinWidth="500" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=scrollviewer}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="23" MaxHeight="60"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="sdasdasdasdsadsadasddasdck" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="sdasdasdasdsadsadasddasdck" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>

</Window>
```

*Note: Please insert your codes (require codes) in your question always. it can help to other people to give you better solutions.*

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to have been an accident in the designer. I went to select the whole UserControl and it selected the first child Grid instead. At least that's what I've had happen before and appears to be the case. So it added a margin to the grid that was much wider than the UserControl itself, and since it was hosted inside yet another control I couldn't see the overflow to spot the issue. Figures that it was something simple. Sigh. I thought I was passed these sorts of snags, lol. Thanks for the responses.